# Deploying/Testing functions with Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: json, node.js, function, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm following [This](https://www.skcript.com/svr/creating-restful-api-firebase/) tutorial, trying to deploy some functions to Firebase, and I can successfully deploy them to my project id. When accessing the following function on the provided URL, I get the error: could not handle the request

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup 
triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database. 
const admin = require ('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.date = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
let format = req.query.format;
const date = moment().format();
res.status(200).json({ date: date});
})
```

My Firebase console logs this on execution:

```
ReferenceError: moment is not defined
at exports.date.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:10:24)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-
functions/lib/providers/https.js:26:41)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:635:7
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:619:9
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

My `package.json` in my `functions` folder has `"moment": "^2.19.1"` under dependencies.

What am I doing wrong? How do I define `moment`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having `moment.js` defined in your `package.json` only means that it'll be installed in the environment where your code runs. To have it available in your code, you need to import the `moment` library:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const moment = require('moment');

const admin = require ('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.date = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  let format = req.query.format;
  const date = moment().format();
  res.status(200).json({ date: date});
})
```

Also see the [moment.js docs for using it in node.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/node-js/).